# Explanation of awk function

Tags: bash, awk

I am converting some bash-style (actually using busybox) scripts to c for usage in a custom kernel driver. Everything is going fine but I'm dreadfully unfamiliar with awk, and would really appreciate an explanation of what this one liner is doing. The function is here:

```
checksum=`echo $sum | busybox awk '{$NF *= -1; print}'`
```

`checksum` and `sum` are standard integers that have been accounted for, and can be either positive or negative. I just have no clue what happens when sum is piped into the awk function.

Comment: correct shell syntax: `checksum=$(echo "$sum" | busybox awk '{$NF *= -1; print}')`

Comment: Ah normally I would agree, but in the shell/parser I'm working requires me to break syntax rules from time to time because it's a garbage api.

Comment: Which one is it forcing you to break here - not quoting variables or using deprecated backticks? or both? Sounds like a dangerous environment to be running shell scripts in either way!

Comment: Believe it or not, both actually! I agree the scripting environment is both dangerous and inconvenient, but in this particular case I have to work with what I have. Luckily, keeping my shell base simple is good inspiration to write better c ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code `awk '{$NF *= -1; print}'` multiplies the value of the last field `$NF` by `-1` in all the lines and then it prints the whole line with the new value assigned to last field `$NF`.

This syntax is often called a shorthand assignment and is equivalent to `$NF=$NF*-1`.  Similarilly we have more shorthand operations like addition and subtraction:

```
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{$NF *=10;print}' #Equivalent to $NF=$NF*10
1 2 30
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{$NF +=10;print}' #Equivalent to $NF=$NF+10
1 2 13
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{$NF -=10;print}' #Equivalent to $NF=$NF-10
1 2 -7
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{$NF /=10;print}' #Equivalent to $NF=$NF/10
1 2 0.3
```

In your case:

```
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{$NF *=-1;print}'
1 2 -3
```

Mind that in awk, each input line - each record, is by default separated by one or more spaces.
Then each line is split into fields starting from `$1` (first field) up to the last field `$NF`.

```
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print $1}'
1
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print $2}'
2
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print $3}'
3
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print $NF}'
3
```

The whole record in awk is called $0:

```
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print $0}'
1 2 3
```

A single print, by default prints the whole line `$0`:

```
$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print}'
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has entirely answered my question and then some!

Comment: Actually here is a question, more so out of curiosity than anything else. I am actually parsing input that uses something similar to `$ echo "1 2 3" |awk '{print}'` just for a single value, so let's say "1" for example. In which case, what is the point of piping it to awk '{print}' if is the same value as echo?

Comment: @robcore If you mean something like this : `echo "1" |awk '{print}'` then there is actually no reason to use awk, since awk will just print `1` , as echo would do. But i think you will not see something like this used anywhere. People use awk to format text, to make calculations, to work with fields, to change the fields separator , etc. A plain piping from echo to awk for a single value has no meaning.

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense. I really appreciate the explanation, given that awk has been my stumbling block for ages :) i finished a driver thanks to you!

Comment: @robcore You are welcome. We all have been in your position. If this answer is suitable for you you might consider to accept this answer as a solution to your question by pressing the green tick - accept answer. Come back for more awk questions any time!

Comment: Ah you even helped me navigate the site. You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Definitely the accepted answer!